# How to run a code a vector and matrix in r?

Tags: r

I need a write a code that include 2 excel files. One of them is

```
proteins
  <chr>   
1 A       
2 C       
3 D       
4 F
```

the other one is the interactions of the proteins.

```
int
      int1 int2
 [1,] "A"  "B" 
 [2,] "B"  "A" 
 [3,] "C"  "A" 
 [4,] "C"  "B" 
 [5,] "B"  "C" 
 [6,] "D"  "B" 
 [7,] "B"  "E" 
 [8,] "D"  "F" 
 [9,] "A"  "F" 
[10,] "D"  "A"
```

in the output I want just the interactions of each other. Because in the interactions files include also B and E proteins. I just want to see "C" "A", "D" "F", "A" "F", "D" A".

I tried for loops. The code;

```
for(row in 1:nrow(int)){
    for(col in 1:ncol(int)){
        for(i in 1:length(proteins)){
          if(proteins[1]== int[row, col]){
            print(int[row , col])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and it did not give an error. Also it didn't run the code. I did not understand the reason of it. I hope I explained the problem clearly. 
Could you please help me?

Comment: "Also it didnt run the code" what does this mean? [Edit] the question and tell us the exact steps you took to reproduce your problem.

Comment: `length(proteins)` is likely returning 1, since it has 1 column. I think your ultimate goal is to filter the interactions data based on those present in `proteins`, is that right? Just filtering?

Comment: `if(proteins[1]== int[row, col]){` lines desent look correct. It should be `if(proteins[i]== int[row, col]){`

Comment: `for` loops are generally a bad idea. Use filter or a join

Comment: @H.B Try the replacement I have suggested above and see if it works. A better way could be to use `apply` families.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As R is a vectorized language you don't need all those loops. You can just run

```
int[apply(int,1, function(x) all(x %in% proteins)),]
```

Comment: what data structures are  `int` and `protein`? matrix? data frame? you can also try this modification `int[apply(int,1, function(x) all(x %in% unlist(proteins))),]`